# JS Перебор массива

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Есть массив ссылок `urls`, нужно его перебрать, затем открыть ссылку и затем закрыть её с задержкой.
Мой код:

```
surf() {
    this.urls.forEach(function(url) {
        window.open(url);
        console.log(url);
        setTimeout(function(){
            window.close();
        }, 10000)
    });
}
```

Но весь нюанс в том, что браузер открывает все ссылки сразу, без каких либо задержек.

P.s. Подскажите в чём может быть проблема (в JS не силён)

Comment: Открывает сразу, потому что ты открываешь сразу, а не в setTimeout, в setTimeout - только закрываешь.

Comment: @Grundy, разобрался, спасибо. Но как тогда открыть первую ссылку без задержки, а всё остальное по порядку с задержкой... Ведь если всё поместить в setTimeout то и первая ссылка будет открываться с задержкой

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> браузер открывает все ссылки сразу, без каких либо задержек

Все это потому, что открытие `window.open` вызывается не внутри `setTimeout`.

Внутри `setTimeout` помещен только `window.close`, однако это тоже ошибка, так как `window` - это текущее окно, а не то, которое было открыто с помощью `window.open`.

[`window.open`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) - возвращает ссылку на открытое окно, именно у этой ссылки и надо вызывать `close`, чтобы закрыть.

---

Чтобы открывать с задержкой - нужно обернуть открытие в `setTimeout`. Если первый элемент не нужно задерживать - можно проверить `index` текущего элемента и если он 0 - не вызывать `setTimeout`

```
this.urls.forEach(function(url,i) {
    setTimeout(()=>{
        var w = window.open(url);
        console.log(url);
        setTimeout(function(){
            w.close();
        }, 10000)
    },i * 1000); // если первый элемент - ставим задержку 0, и окно появится сразу после выполнения цикла, иначе ждем пропорционально индексу
});
```

---

Можно так же упомянуть, что в таком виде открываемые окна могут быть блокированы браузером, так как открываются не в результате действий пользователя.

Comment: Grundy, Cпасибо за развёрнутый ответ. При двух элементов в массиве (ссылок) всё работает отлично, но если их больше 2, то после открытия первой ссылки открываются сразу все остальные

Comment: @Алексей, поправил код в ответе